# Jetpack compose saving productsList depend on categoryId when Re-press categoryItem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack compose, what is the best way to save data, If I have the LazyRow for categories and LazyColumn for Products, I want when the user Re-press the category Item doesn't make a new request to get data instead of that it gives to him the data that he saved temporarily, I used something like that but it's not working because when I Re-press it gives me old data or empty list I don't know why this is the code, instead of products i use natural images.

this Screen:

```
@Composable
fun NaturalCategoriesScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    lazyGridState: LazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState(),
    naturalViewModel: NaturalViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val state by naturalViewModel.statue.collectAsState()
    val categoryState by naturalViewModel.categorySelectState.collectAsState()

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val shouldStartPaginate = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            naturalViewModel.canPaginate && (
                    lazyGridState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index ?: -18) >=
                    (lazyGridState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 15)
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = shouldStartPaginate.value) {
        if (shouldStartPaginate.value && naturalViewModel.listState == ListState.IDLE) {
            if (categoryState.categoryItem == ALL_CATEGORIES)
                naturalViewModel.getALLNaturalsWhenLoadingMoreData()
            else naturalViewModel.getNaturalsByCategoryWhenLoadingMoreData(
                categoryState.categoryId,
                categoryState.categoryItem
            )
        }
    }

    when (state.all_loading){
        true -> {
            NaturalCategoryShimmer()
        }
        false ->NaturalScreenContent(
            naturalUIModel = state.naturalUiModel,
            categoriesList = state.categoryUiModel,
            state = lazyGridState,
            listState = naturalViewModel.listState,
            coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
            categorySelected = categoryState,
            onSelectCategoryItem = { id, name ->
                if (name == ALL_CATEGORIES) {
                    naturalViewModel.onSelectALLNaturalCategory()
                    naturalViewModel.getAllNaturalData()
                } else {
                    naturalViewModel.onSelectAnyCategoryItem(categoryName = name, categoryID = id)
                    naturalViewModel.getNaturalsDataByCategory(
                        categoryID = id,
                        categoryName = name
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

and ViewModel :

```
@HiltViewModel
class NaturalViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val naturalByCategoryUseCase: GetNaturalByNaturalCategoryUseCase,
    private val naturalCategoryUseCase: GetNaturalCategoryUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(NaturalUIState())
    val statue = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private var page by mutableStateOf(FIRST_PAGE)
    var canPaginate by mutableStateOf(CAN_PAGING)
    var listState by mutableStateOf(ListState.IDLE)

    private val _categorySelectState = MutableStateFlow(CategoryItemSelectedState())
    val categorySelectState = _categorySelectState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        onAllLoading()
        getNaturalImagesCategory()
        getNaturals(INITIAL_CATEGORY_ID, INITIAL_CATEGORY_NAME, ALL_NATURAL)

    }

    private fun getNaturalImagesCategory() {
        onAllLoading()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        categoryUiModel = naturalCategoryUseCase().toNaturalCategoryModel(),
                        all_loading = false
                    )
                }
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                onError(e)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getNaturals(
        categoryID: Int,
        categoryName: String,
        chooseType: String
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (
                page == FIRST_PAGE ||
                (page != FIRST_PAGE && canPaginate) &&
                listState == ListState.IDLE
            ) {
                listState = if (page == FIRST_PAGE) ListState.LOADING else ListState.PAGINATING
                try {
                    naturalByCategoryUseCase(
                        NaturalListByCategoryProperties(
                            pageSize = LIST_PAGE_SIZE,
                            pageNumber = page,
                            categoryID = categoryID,
                            categoryName = categoryName,
                            chooseType = chooseType
                        )
                    )
                        .filterNotNull()
                        .catch {
                            onError(it)
                        }.collect { naturals ->
                            canPaginate = naturals.size == LIST_PAGE_SIZE
                            if (page == FIRST_PAGE) {
                                _uiState.update { it.copy(naturalUiModel = emptyList()) }
                                _uiState.update {
                                    it.copy(
                                        naturalUiModel = naturals.toNaturalUIModel()
                                    )
                                }
                            } else {
                                _uiState.update {
                                    it.copy(
                                        naturalUiModel = _uiState.value.naturalUiModel +
                                                naturals.toNaturalUIModel()

                                    )
                                }
                            }
                            listState = ListState.IDLE
                            if (canPaginate)
                                page++
                            else {
                                listState =
                                    if (page == FIRST_PAGE) {
                                        _uiState.update {
                                            it.copy(
                                                error = "There IS Something Wrong",
                                                all_loading = false
                                            )
                                        }
                                        ListState.ERROR
                                    } else
                                        ListState.PAGINATION_EXHAUST
                            }
                        }
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    onError(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getNaturalsDataByCategory(
        categoryID: Int,
        categoryName: String,
    ) {
        page = FIRST_PAGE
        _uiState.update { it.copy(naturalUiModel = emptyList()) }
        getNaturals(
            categoryID,
            categoryName,
            chooseType = NATURAL_BY_CATEGORY
        )
    }

    fun getNaturalsByCategoryWhenLoadingMoreData(
        categoryID: Int,
        categoryName: String,
    ) {
        getNaturals(
            categoryID,
            categoryName,
            chooseType = NATURAL_BY_CATEGORY
        )
    }

    fun getALLNaturalsWhenLoadingMoreData() {
        getNaturals(
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_ID,
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_NAME,
            chooseType = ALL_NATURAL
        )
    }

    fun getAllNaturalData() {
        page = FIRST_PAGE
        _uiState.update { it.copy(naturalUiModel = emptyList()) }
        getNaturals(
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_ID,
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_NAME,
            chooseType = ALL_NATURAL
        )
    }

    fun onSelectALLNaturalCategory() {
        _categorySelectState.update {
            it.copy(
                categoryItem = ALL_CATEGORIES,
                categoryId = INITIAL_CATEGORY_ID
            )
        }
    }

    fun onSelectAnyCategoryItem(categoryName: String, categoryID: Int) {
        _categorySelectState.update {
            it.copy(
                categoryItem = categoryName,
                categoryId = categoryID
            )
        }
    }
```

and this the code like what i was trying to do :

```
    var selectedCategory by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    val cachedProducts = remember { mutableStateMapOf<String, List<String>>() }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            categories.forEach { category ->
                Button(onClick = {
                    if (!cachedProducts.containsKey(category)) {
                        // Simulate API request
                        cachedProducts[category] = products[category] ?: emptyList()
                    }
                    selectedCategory = category
                }) {
                    Text(category)
                }
            }
        }

        val productList = cachedProducts[selectedCategory] ?: emptyList()
```